# C builder RAD 2010 RTL/VCL Application->Terminate() Function NOT TERMINATING THE APPLICATION

Tags: c++builder, vcl, rad

I have a problem also described here: http://www.delphigroups.info/3/9/106748.html

I have tried almost all forms of placing Application->Terminate() func everywhere in the code, following and not 'return 0', 'ExitProcess(0)', 'ExitThread(0)', exit(0). No working variant closes the app. Instead the code after Application->Terminate() statement is running.

I have two or more threads in the app. I tried calling terminate func in created after execution threads and in main thread.

Also this is not related (as far as I can imagine) with CodeGuard / madExcept (I have turned it off and on, no effect). CodeGuard turning also did not do success.

The only working code variant is to place Application->Terminate() call to any of any form button's OnClick handler. But this does not fit in my needs. I need to terminate in any place.

What I should do to terminate all the threads in C++ Builder 2010 application and then terminate the process?

Answer (score 3):

[Application->Terminate()](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_Terminate.html) does not close application immediately, it only signals you want to close the application.

> Terminate calls the Windows API
>   PostQuitMessage function to perform an
>   orderly shutdown of the application.
>   **Terminate is not immediate.**

In your functions call [Application->ProcessMessages()](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_ProcessMessages.html) then check if the [Application->Terminated](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_Terminated.html) property is true.

> For applications using
>   calculation-intensive loops, call
>   ProcessMessages  periodically, and
>   also check Terminated to determine
>   whether to abort the calculation and
>   allow the application to terminate

For example:

```
void Calc()
{
  for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; ++x)
  {
    // perform complex calculation

    // check if need to exit
    Application->ProcessMessages();
    if (Application->Terminated)
    {
      break;
    } // end if
  } // end for

  // clean up
}
```

Comment: But what conditions should met? I wait for app closing for about 2 minutes and nothing happen..

Comment: I found the only way to really terminate my program in any place is to call these sequence:

FormDestroy(); // also any memory free blocks i put here
TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0)

Comment: @ergey I have expanded my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks! It really fixes the thing. Now i am terminating through App->Terminate(), then in loop call ProcessMessages() and check for Terminated flag then return from child thread.
But i wonder when really the RTL sets this flag? After terminating main thread or shutting down just VCL/RTL ? But if they do so i teoretically can't call any stdlib/stdio functions, because RTL is down, or there is another meaning of terminated flag.

Comment: @ergey.  From the help: *ProcessMessages sets Terminated to true when it receives a WM_QUIT message.*